# Ruby on Rails Devise edit registration form with ability to select or add a separate model (e.g. Company)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a User model and a Company model (amongst others) and an "Edit Profile" page with a form. One field of the form is to select a company from a list and save to the Users table in a column called "company_id", which is linked to the ID of each Company in the Companies table.

This all works great.

However, I would prefer to have a text field in which a user can start typing a company name and select a suggestion or create a new Company if theirs is not in the database.

I'm new to ruby and would like to know the best way to do this if anyone can help.

**app\views\devise\registrations\edit.html.erb**

```
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
        <div id="errorexplanationcontainer"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', autofocus: true %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="first_name">First name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input' %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="last_name">Last name</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Company Field -->            

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :company_id %>
          <%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|company| [company.name, company.id]}, {:include_blank => "Select One"}, id: :job_company_id %>
        </div>

        <!-- End -->

        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.text_field :job_title, class: 'mdl-textfield__input' %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="job_title">Job Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'mdl-textfield__input' %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
          <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', autocomplete: "off" %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">New password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', autocomplete: "off" %>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm password</label>
        </div>
        <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
          UPDATE
        </button>
        <dialog class="mdl-dialog">
          <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Save Changes</h4>
          Re-enter your password to save changes to your account.
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
            <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', autocomplete: "off" %>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="current_password">Current password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
              <%= f.submit "UPDATE", class: 'hideinput' %>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">CANCEL</button>
          </div>
        </dialog>
        <script>
          var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
          var showDialogButton = document.querySelector('#show-dialog');
          if (! dialog.showModal) {
            dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
          }
          showDialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            dialog.showModal();
          });
          dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
            dialog.close();
          });
        </script>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Twitter typeahead in on of my projects. It is pretty smooth and light, you just have to pass an array to it and it does the trick for you.

Some detailed documentation and examples are listed here: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Bundle install [twitter-typeahead-rails](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails)

In your `application.js`, add the following line above `require_tree`:

```
//= require twitter/typeahead.min
```

In your controller, you can initialize the array:

```
@companies = Company.pluck(:name)
```

In your view:

```
<div id='search'>
  <%= f.text_field :company, class: 'mdl-textfield__input' %>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var companies = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: #{@companies},
});
$('#search .mdl-textfield__input').typeahead('destroy').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 2
},
{
  source: companies
});
```

Comment: Your answer cab be improved better if you provide the related context in the answer itself. Providing just links won't be useful if the targeted site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi Farhan, thanks for your help. The only problem is, while I want the user to type in the company name, I want the application to find the company if it exists and submit the id of the company to the company_id field in the users table. If the company exists, I want it to add a new company to the companies table and submit the id of that new company to the company_id field in the users table.

Comment: In that case, you need to use ajax to fetch and create company in realtime, However, I don't prefer that, in above case, when the user submits the form you can query in the user `create` action as `Company.where(name: params[:company]).first_or_create` which will solve the purpose.